# nav-menu-template and columns in sub menu

Tags: menus

I am trying to use the wordpress menu setup and have a working horizontal menu with a drop down submenu. Unfortunately the sub enu is quite long so I wanted to split it into columns

I can do it if I hardcode the menu into header.php but that means I have to add new items rather than letting the client do it.

This is a parred down version of what I am trying to achieve

```
    <div class="headermenucss">

<ul id="topnav">
<li><a href="home.html" class="home">home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html" class="home">About Us</a>
    <div class="sub">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li> 
    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
    <li><a href="terms.html">Terms</a></li>
    <li><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
    <li><a href="staff.html">Staff</a></li>
    <li><a href="vacancies.html">Vacancies</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</li>

<li><a href="clients.html" class="home">clients</a></li>
<li><a href="media_centre.html" class="home">media centre</a></li>
<li><a href="contact_us.html" class="home">contact us</a></li>
<li><a href="sitemap.html" class="home">site map</a></li>   
</ul>

</div>
```

So what I need to do is to be able to loop through the child items and add in the  etc as necessary.

Any tips, advice or anyone done this before?? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier for you if you'd stick with the old menu output and used css to emulate your submenu columns. You can left-float the elements in your submenu (while giving them an appropriate with - e.g. 33% for 3 columns), which sorts them horizontally rather than vertically, but otherwise will give you a column-like effect.

Comment: That's a really good idea, took about 2 mins!